# Singleton in AppServiceProvider causes error in fresh migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a singleton registered in my `AppServiceProvider` which loads a Currency model.

The problem appears to be that if you run a migration on an empty database, it is trying to load this Currency model before the migration has been done.  (So no Currencies table, or currency row exists yet).

How can I get the currency migration to run first, before it tries to load this singleton?

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Breadcrumbs::class, function($app){
            return new Breadcrumbs();
        });

        $this->app->singleton(Currency::class, function($app){
            return Currency::current();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs, Currency $currency)
    {
        View::composer(['partials.*'], function($view) use ($breadcrumbs){
            $view->with('breadcrumbs', $breadcrumbs);
        });

        View::composer('*', function($view) use ($currency){
            $view->with([
                'me'        => Auth::user(),
                'currency'  => $currency
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

And the migration fails, with:

```
  TypeError 

  Argument 2 passed to App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::boot() must be an instance of App\Models\Currency, null given, called in /home/vagrant/reviewmarket/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php on line 36

  at app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:34
     30▕      * Bootstrap any application services.
     31▕      *
     32▕      * @return void
     33▕      */
  ➜  34▕     public function boot(Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs, Currency $currency)
     35▕     {
     36▕         View::composer(['partials.*'], function($view) use ($breadcrumbs){
     37▕             $view->with('breadcrumbs', $breadcrumbs);
     38▕         });

      +7 vendor frames 
  8   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))

      +5 vendor frames 
  14  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't add parameters in `boot()`

```php
public function boot()
{
    $breadcrumbs = Breadcrumbs::all();
    $currency = Currency::all();

    View::composer(['partials.*'], function ($view) use ($breadcrumbs) {
        $view->with('breadcrumbs', $breadcrumbs);
    });

    View::composer('*', function ($view) use ($currency) {
        $view->with([
            'me'        => Auth::user(),
            'currency'  => $currency
        ]);
    });
}
```

fix like this

> Laravel internally call it boot function like  `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::boot()` and when you add 2 parameter in boot method  then `boot()` function must send 2 parameter that Couse error